# Configure swagger with JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, swagger

I want install SWAGER for my SpringBoot application. Seems that JWT doesn't give access for swagger URL.

I'm trying to reach this by url `localhost:8088/swagger-ui.html`

Here is SwaggerConfig class

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {


@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("Path.to.my.controller"))

            .build();

}


}
```

Also i was trying to add WebAppConfig from [link](http://qaru.site/questions/73659/a-simple-way-to-implement-swagger-in-a-spring-mvc-application) with the next content

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}

}
```

And tried to set ignore url:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

}
```

This version of code gives autoredirection to "localhost:8088/login" from swagger url. But the next returns just empty page

**UPDATED**

```
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
```

The urls in gaps are urls i was seen when was debuging issuse. This urls are called by swagger.

**UPDATED part End**

Main class

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    app.run();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public FilterRegistrationBean jwtFilterRegistration(JwtUtil jwtUtil, UserService userService) {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new JwtFilter(jwtUtil, userService));

    filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

    // ordering in the filter chain
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(1);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}

// Request Interceptor for checking permission with custom annotation.
@Bean
public MappedInterceptor PermissionHandlerInterceptor() {
    return new MappedInterceptor(null, new PermissionHandlerInterceptor());
}
```

}

Pom xml contains all needed depencies. When i comment in Main class jwt method i can access swagger. So i made a conclusion that problem in JWT.
If some extra info is needed i will add.

**UPDATED**

At first swagger-url gives White Label Page with an error "Unathorized"
After some manipulations with code it gives empty page.

Comment: Not sure, its a typo, ur link : localhost:8088/swagger-ui.hmtl , check the html part, otherwise can check ur code

Comment: I've updated a little. Yes, it was a typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently had to do the same. You need to tell your Spring Security to permit all Swagger resources. Try this:

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .csrf().disable()


.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

            // don't create session

.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
.and()          

            .authorizeRequests()

            // allow anonymous resource requests
            .antMatchers(
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/",
                    "/v2/api-docs",           // swagger
                    "/webjars/**",            // swagger-ui webjars
                    "/swagger-resources/**",  // swagger-ui resources
                    "/configuration/**",      // swagger configuration
                    "/*.html",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    // Custom JWT based security filter
    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    // disable page caching
    httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
}
```

This is my Swagger docket configuration. It also include the Authorization Header in case you want to apply you token to all endpoint.

```
@Bean
public Docket newsApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()))
            .apiInfo(generateApiInfo());
}

@Bean
SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}

List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
            = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return Lists.newArrayList(
            new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
}

private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header");
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly ,I had to ignore adding the   HttpMethod.GET in the antMatcher array as it was giving errors